# Interpolation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I've done an interpolation but I don't know if it's possible to save the data. For example. This is my code:

```
load ab1.txt
x= ab1(:,2);
y= ab1(:,3);
z= 399.25:1:2179.5;
yi= interp1(x,y,z);
plot(x,y,'o',z,yi)
```

I have a lot of values like 352.4, 352.5 354.3... and I want to get, with the interpolation, only one value from every number.For example,  for the value 352 I want to get the value of the interpolation. Is that possible? Or I will have to do something different like mediums or something like that?

Comment: Are you sure you used `interp1` as you intended? As you did it now, it takes the dataseries `(x,y)` and interpolates for the values `z=[399.25 400.25 401.25 402.25 .... 2178.25 2179.25]`. So it's normal you get a lot of values in return, since you asked to find the interpolant of a lot of values. Saving data is done with the [save function](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/save.html).

Comment: Hi Gunther, thanks for your answer. At the end, I decided to do in excel the averages to calculate one of each value. So, for example, if I had 352.3= 0.5 and 352.4=0.628, I calculated 352= 0.564. Well, the problem now is I need values for each number. I mean... for example, if I have 352 and 354, I need also the number 353. I think I'll have to do it with interpolation. I will try to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
y352 = interp1(X,Y,352)
```

gives you the interpolated value at 352.

8 AUGUST 2012 EDIT: Then OP comments

> Thanks mwengler! But the problem is I need to find missing values with interpolation. For example. I have 350, 351, 353, 354 (x) with their values (y). And I need that Matlab identify that the number 352 is missed and to find their value with interpolation. Is that possible? Thanks a lot! :) – user1578688 yesterday

From your other comment, you consider an integer number N to be missing if there are no true samples in X that are in range `N<=x<N+1`.  So the answer to your question is:
1) find missing numbers and make an array of them
2) interpolate values of those numbers only.

```
X = sort(X); % make sure our X go from least to most in order
XasInt = floor(X); % the integer X at each X value
XasIntFullRange = (X(1):X(end))'; % all X including "missing" values
XasIntMissing = setdiff(XasIntFullRange,XasInt); % just the missing ones
YasIntMissing = interp1(X,Y,XasIntMissing); % interpolated values of the missing
```

Comment: Thanks mwengler! But the problem is I need to find missing values with interpolation. For example. I have 350, 351, 353, 354 (x) with their values (y). And I need that Matlab identify that the number 352 is missed and to find their value with interpolation. Is that possible? Thanks a lot! :)